# What does Asset Allocations mean in adb shell dumpsys meminfo

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me what does  Asset Allocations mean in adb shell dumpsys meminfo Android?
I see this at start up my android device and I see my application's resources.arsc is consuming 516K even though my app is not running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With `resources.arsc`, there are two things that can happen.

Normally, the file is stored in the .apk uncompressed. Android `mmap()`s the file and just reads from it as necessary, without loading the whole file into RAM.

If it's compressed however, direct random access into the file is no longer an option, so it gets decompressed and kept in memory for further operations (e.g. loading a string).

I'm not sure why this would be the case if the app is not running. Perhaps it's kept around as a [background process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14259504/469220)?

Comment: why just Android uncompressed it and copy it into data/data or do some thing first to apt then put it in data/app, so that  apk file can be smaller?

Comment: I don't have a good answer. I think you would have to compromise either way. If you save it to `/data/data`, you waste disk space. If you load it into RAM, you waste RAM. Is your file big enough for that allocation to be a problem?

Comment: Yes, now it has a nearly 30mb size, resource.arsc file is 6mb. Because it has a lot language inside.Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know any easy way. You can provide those languages as separate xml or json files in the apk, and build a loader for them. Then even if they're compressed, you'll never have to load all of them at the same time. If you want to minimize changes to your code, [this](http://comserv.cs.ut.ee/forms/ati_report/downloader.php?file=FE07EAE132DBEEBE7231CEFB0E0200EA2E6E508E) might help.