# Android - Difference between running process and cached background process

Tags: android

I've already read through the existing questions about this but I still have a few questions.

So if a user swipes away the app from recent apps, does it then become a cached background process or is it completely gone?

Why are some running proccesses such as the camera a running process instead of cached background proccess since it only has 1 process running and no services. How is this still a running process? It isn't in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

**So, what are "cached background processes"?**

Since you are asking for a technical interpretation of something listed in a device UI, the definition may vary by device, if device manufacturers elected to tinker with the Settings app.

That being said, "cached background processes" usually refers to processes that do not have a foreground activity and do not have a running service. These processes are kept in memory simply because we have enough memory to do so, and therefore, as you note, the user can switch back to these processes quickly. As Android starts to need more system RAM for yet other processes, the "cached background processes" tend to be the processes that get terminated to free up system RAM.

The pre-eminent example of a "cached background process" would be one where the user launched the app, poked around it briefly, then pressed HOME to return to the home screen. If the process does not have a running service, I would expect to find it listed as a "cached background process".

For more information follow the previous question : [On Android, what's the difference between running processes and cached background processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259504/on-android-whats-the-difference-between-running-processes-and-cached-backgroun)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've had a read through that post but, in my running apps, the camera has 1 running process and no running services. It is not in the foreground but is still a running process instead of cached background process. Why is this?