# Programmatically clear cached background process

Tags: java, android, caching, background-process

I've developed a simple application that loads four mobile webviews side by side.
On a fresh install the app fully opens and loads these pages in under 0.5 seconds.
However if i minimize this app, for some reason its "cached background process" is over 200mbs! sometimes 250... Seems completely unnecessary as the app loads lightning fast on a fresh install

How can I clear this cache when the app is minimized (onbackpressed etc)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to worry about cached memory as system will reclaim it when required.

however if still you want to do something about it you can call `finish()` in your `onStop()` method.

also [this is a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259661/1529129) on this topic by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).

> "cached background processes" usually refers to processes that do not
>   have a foreground activity and do not have a running service. These
>   processes are kept in memory simply because we have enough memory to
>   do so, and therefore, as you note, the user can switch back to these
>   processes quickly. As Android starts to need more system RAM for yet
>   other processes, the "cached background processes" tend to be the
>   processes that get terminated to free up system RAM

Comment: finish() didn't clear the cache. But System.exit(0); in the onStop() method worked

Comment: @David yes it does not. but calling System.exit(0); is not recommended.

Comment: Makes more sense then caching 250mb for no reason at all, only to have to clear that memory when its needed.

Comment: well we should leave that on OS to decide :)

Comment: I've put it in onBackPressed instead of onStop