# Stop Android service in activity onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-service, activity-lifecycle

I try to manage a Android **foreground** service to upload data to server. One of the requirements is to kill the service when the user close the app (e.g. swiping up to close app). The service is started in the onStart lifecycle with startService of Activity A and killed in **onDestroy** by stopService in the same activity. When I close the app and go to:

Developer options > Running Services > Show cached processes

I can see my app is still there and occupying system memory. The interesting thing is if I stopService in **onStop** lifecycle and when the app is closed, my app is no longer in the cached processes list. My question is is there a way to prevent the app from being caching in the system by still stopService in onDestroy lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

According to official android documentation:
[Link of foreground service docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

> To remove the service from the foreground, call `stopForeground()`. This
> method takes a boolean, which indicates whether to remove the status
> bar notification as well. Note that the service continues to run.
>
> If you stop the service while it's running in the foreground, its
> notification is removed.

For understanding of cached processes.

[Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259504/on-android-whats-the-difference-between-running-processes-and-cached-backgroun#:%7E:text=That%20being%20said%2C%20%22cached%20background,back%20to%20these%20processes%20quickly)

Comment: I also try stopForeground() and then stopSelf() in service by starting that service in activity onDestroy() with:

        `val intent = Intent(this, myService::class.java)
         intent.setAction(ACTION_DESTROY_SERVICE_FROM_CLIENT)
         startService(intent)`

The action ACTION_DESTROY_SERVICE_FROM_CLIENT in myService is to stopForeground() and then stopSelf() but it doesn't work.